# How to mimic the behavior of the iPhone Mail app when entering email addresses?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I was wondering whether any of you may have an idea how to mimic the behavior of the native Mail app on the iPhone, when selecting email contacts in the To/CC lines.
If you note carefully, when touching that line the keyboard opens and you get a cursor, which is like the normal behavior of a UITextField. However, after keying a name and selecting it, the name is added inside a blue bubble. Still fine - one could create the bubble and move the text field. However, if you go back using the backspace key - the blue bubble becomes marked (darker blue), the cursor disappears, but the keyboard stays visible.
Any idea how to accomplish that?

Thanks!
Ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Three20 control library from the Facebook: https://github.com/facebook/three20

Either the TTMessageController, or the TTPickerTextField control are what you want. For using TTPickerTextField there's a good demo here: https://github.com/shayne/TTPickerTextFieldDemo

Comment: Thanks Paul. I just took a quick look at Three20, will need to look at it deeper for sure. Anyway, what I'm looking for is a bit different - I don't actually need to pick from a data source etc., I just want to mimic the UI behavior of the blue bubbles with the cursor disappearing. I actually need it within a large text view, where items are embedded inside and become "bubbles" within the text. I was wondering - do you know how technically you can remove the cursor while leaving the keyboard on etc.? Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm not sure about hiding the cursor. My advice would be to look through the source code of the Three20 control and see if you can modify it for your purpose.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I'll do. Thanks a lot!